# How to check validity of form when it messes with a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a normal form with some textboess that are required.
So when these textboxes are not filled, the HTML5 shows that warning in each field.

What I wanted to do is to show a nice notification when everything is filled. And it is working correctly, but id does not check if the textboxes are filled..

```
document.querySelector('#submit1').onclick = function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    swal("Thank you!", "Your request has been submitted.", "success");
};
```

I took it a step forward and it checks the inputs before submitting, but the popup does not show up now. It takes me to the same page.

```
document.querySelector('#submit1').onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();       
    if (if ($('#contact-form')[0].checkValidity()) {
    swal("Thank you!", "Your request has been submitted.", "success");
     }
    return;
};
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Thank you

```
<form id="contact-form" action="" name="contactform" class="row" method="post" >
<input required type="text" name="first_name" id="name"> 
<input required type="password" name="first_name" id="name"> 
<input type="submit" id="submit1">
</form>
```

Comment: remove the indexer perhaps.

Comment: Do you mean the [0] ?

Answer (score 0):

Whats the extra if in the function

**if(** if ($('#contact-form')[0].checkValidity()) {

It should be:

```
if ($('#contact-form').checkValidity()) {
    swal("Thank you!", "Your request has been submitted.", "success");
}
```

There are some assumptions I am making here:
1. you have checkValidity() as some method attached to your form.
2. swal is some custom function

Also, you can use

```
$('#submit1').on('click', function(e) {
});
```

or

```
$('#submit1').click(function(e) {
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort but now the validity does not work and the popup also. here is my form ` <form id="contact-form" action="" name="contactform" class="row" method="post" >`

Comment: I noticed that if you have e.preventDefault(), it will not trigger validation. checkValidity doesnt seem to work properly here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement.checkValidity